# Number of ways to arrange COLORADO with the last letter being O

Tags: combinatorics

Obviously without the last letter restriction there are 8!/3! number of permutations. Clearly, we remove one of the Os and get 7! permutations (if the Os were distinguishable). Now, when accounting for the "double counting" do we divide by 2! or 3!? Clearly we could've  set aside any of the three Os and so I would think we still need to do 7!/3!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the remaining letters can indeed be permutated in $7! $ ways, but then for each permutation we can also interchange the two O's, so we have to divide by $2!=2 $. The final answer is hence $7!/2!=2520 $.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why it doesn't matter which O we removed. Don't we have to account for all three possibilities?

Comment: No, since we "set an O apart" at the very beginning. What if we had to find the number of ways to arange COLORADOOOOO with the last 5 letters being an O. The answer shouldn't be different since we only permute the first $7 $ letters. We just leave the last $5 $ letters for where they are so they don't matter in the calculation.

Comment: I guess I was confused because if we look at the entire permutation space (of size 8!) then there are permutations for all three choices of last O. However, I see that there are always 7!/2! arrangements no matter our choice.

Comment: I'm trying to construct the solution without "setting aside" an O. I see that 3/8 of the 8! permutations will have an O as the last letter. Then, we need to divide this by 3! (3*8!/8*3!) = 7!/2! Anything wrong with this argument?

Comment: Seems like a good argument as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let us count the ways to arrange `COLPRADQ` with the last letter being either `O`, `P`, or `Q`.

Now there are $3$ ways to select which to put in last place, and there are $7!$ ways to arrange the remaining letters.

Therefore there are $\;3\times 7!\;$ ways to arrange `COLPRADQ` with the last letter being either `O`, `P`, or `Q`.

Now if we replace the `P` and `Q` with `O`s, so that they become indistinct from the other, then every arrangement is now one of $3!$ equivalent arrangements.

So the count of *distinct* arrangements of `COLORADO` where the last letter is one of the `O`s, is $\dfrac{3\times 7!}{3!}$.

This is $\;\dfrac{7!}{2!}\;$ due to cancellation.

---

This is the same result as counting ways to:  Select any one of the three `O`, then arrange the remaining seven symbols including the remaining two indistinguishable `O`s.  That is: $1\times \frac{7!}{2!}$

---

Does that help you intuit the solution?